# Android Navigate to nested fragment from other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

There is MainActivity that has 3 Tab pages. Tab pages implemented as fragments.
On 3rd PersonalFragment there are also tabs (but above not below).

And the third tab there is DownloadManager.

**How to navigate to that nested DownloadManager from any activity?**

I guess that it should be via Android Intent with some EXTRA string e.g.

```
public class MainActivity
```

...

```
    public static void startDownloadManager(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PAGE, PAGE_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String place = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PAGE);
        if (place.equals(PAGE_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER)){
            openDownloadManager();
        }       
    }


    private void openDownloadManager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

And the n in `openDownloadManager()` I would call some PersonalFragment  methods, then it would call nested Fragment methods ...
So is it way to go?